# Find the right regexpr pattern for :

Tags: regex

Finding all blocs of 6 and 8 digits not folowed or preceded by a digit :

Ex :

```
123456-222222VALUE_X334455667788STACKOVERFLOW12345678()333333KO-987654,36CODING6
```

You should find :

```
123456
222222
12345678
333333
987654
```

What the regexpr pattern sould be ?

This one doesn't work:

```
(^|\D)((\d{6})|(\d{8}))($|\D)/g
```

Why the `222222` bloc doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` after `123456` is matched and consumed with the `($|\D)` pattern part during the first iteration, thus, it is a better idea to use `(?!\d)` (or `(?=$|\D`, but `(?!\d)` is faster).

You may use

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{6}(?:\d{2})?)(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JKVfLG/1)

**Details**

- `(?:^|\D)` - start of string or any non-digit
- `(\d{6}(?:\d{2})?)` - Group 1: 6 digits followed optionally with 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit after the 6 or 8 digits allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative look-ahead and negative look-behind concepts for this as given below:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{6}|\d{8})(?!\d)
```

`(?<!\d)` is negative look-behind to make sure number is not preceded by a digit.

`(?!\d)` is negative look-ahedto make sure number is not followed by a digit.

You can see this regular expression in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/9xEyTH/2)

Answer (score 0):

I keep this solution : (?:^|\D)(\d{6}(?:\d{2})?)(?!\d)

Thank you everybody for all.
That's run.
Have a nice day
Bye